# How to get the Jquery Autocomplete plugin to display Solr Documents returned?

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, solr

I am using spring MVC 4.X and Solr setup to index and query my data, But I am new to Jquery/JavaScript world.
I found a code snippet that queries directly from JSP page the Solr URL. But I think its not a good idea
to couple view with business logic, I wrote a controller that intercepts the search query and returns a 
list of SolrDocuments.

Can Anyone please tell me what needs to be modified so that it displays the result in UI, I am returning the response as JSON or at least I hope so.

Request from UI

```
$(function() {
        $("#searchBox").autocomplete({
            source : function(request, response) {
                var searchField = $('#searchBox').val();
                var URL = "${home}/searchsolr?query=" + searchField;
                $.ajax({
                    url : URL,
                    success : function(data) {
                        var docs = JSON.stringify(data.response.docs);

                        var jsonData = JSON.parse(docs);
                        response($.map(jsonData, function(value, key) {
                            return {
                                label : value.name
                            }
                        }));
                    },
                    dataType : 'jsonp',
                    jsonp : 'json.wrf'
                });
            },
            minLength : 1
        })
    });
```

The SearchController relevant snippet

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/searchsolr")
    public  @ResponseBody SolrDocumentList getSearchResultFromSolr(ModelMap model ,@RequestParam("query") String  queryText) {
        System.out.println("INSIDE SOLR SEARCH");
        ProdLookupService  bls = new ProdLookupService();
        System.out.println("query text is "+queryText);
        SolrDocumentList sdl =bls.findList(queryText);
        System.out.println("goin to return");
        return sdl;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better you use normal REST calls to Solr to get the data rather than the Java API . First of all , your JQuery and Controller based approach is good . So maintain a flow like this . Use JQuery to call your Controller like you are doing right now . Then , in controller make an HTTP GET call to get data out of Solr, don't use Solr API. While you are sending query and all other parameters also pass wt=json as a parameter . This way you will receive a JSON from Solr .Pass all your parameters in an encoded String . After you receive the data, you can easily send the data back to your JQuery Ajax as a JSON String. Then you can parse this  response in JQuery according to your needs.

Comment: Hi, I have made it to work . I was doing a mistake that I was not returning the response as AjaxResponse. Changed my controller to RestController and returned response as Ajax Response , then parsed this response in the $ajax :success method. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Great !! would like you to accept my answer if it helped you in any way :) .